# How to select tensor element by other index tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let me give some example that I want.

```
print(num_tensor.get_shape())
>> [5, 6]

sess.run(num_tensor)
>> [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
   [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
   [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
   [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
   [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]]

print(index_tensor.get_shape()) # Same with num_tensor.get_shape[0]
>> [5]

sess.run(index_tensor)
>> [0, 2, 1, 3, 4]
```

I want to make the new tensor to select element of num_tensor by index_tensor.

```
new_tensor = ... # Some operations
print(new_tensor.get_shape())
>> [5]
sess.run(new_tensor)
>> [0, 8, 13, 21, 28]
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: SOLVED. ```tf.gather``` may help this task.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if you answered your own question below, giving a little more detail.

Comment: Thank you, @jabalazs. With ```index_tensor = tf.constant([[0, 0], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 3], [4, 4]])```, ```new_tensor = tf.gather_nd(num_tensor, index_tensor)``` gives me exactly what I wanted.

Comment: As a little warning tf.gather_nd does not have gradients computed in tensorflow.

Comment: @Steven gather_nd gradients are available https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5342